# Error in fetching data from datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

here in my code I didn't understand what's happening here when I'm attaching screenshots here.

[image: Image 1]

here it shows value of `selectedRow.Cells(13).Value` also showing value of all cells

[image: Image 2]

but when debugger goes on line `name.Text = selectedRow.Cells(12).Value` all values becomes `Nothing`

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

Now I'm confused what's the matter?

Code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellMouseDoubleClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim selectedRow = DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to update this data?", "Want to update data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        If result = DialogResult.No Then
            Dim result2 As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this data?", "Delete Data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            If result2 = DialogResult.No Then
            ElseIf result2 = DialogResult.Yes Then
                cmd.CommandText = "Delete * from [Transaction] where [receipt_id]=" & selectedRow.Cells(0).Value & ""
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Button2.PerformClick()
            End If
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
            str = "select * from [Transaction] where [receipt_id]=" & selectedRow.Cells(0).Value & ""
            cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, cn)
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(ds, "Transaction")

            'Add Columns
            If ds.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso ds.Tables("Transaction").Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Class_Name.Text = selectedRow.Cells(13).Value
                section.Text = selectedRow.Cells(14).Value
                name.Text = selectedRow.Cells(12).Value
                gr_num.Text = selectedRow.Cells(10).Value
                roll_no.Text = selectedRow.Cells(11).Value
                receipt_no.Text = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value
                pay_mode.Text = selectedRow.Cells(2).Value
                cheque_no.Text = selectedRow.Cells(7).Value
                bank_name.Text = selectedRow.Cells(9).Value
            End If
            End If
    End If

End Sub
```

After I debug code and all I see everything happens because of this function

```
 Public Sub get_name_list()
    Try
        Dim ctr, i As Integer
        ds.Clear()
        name.ResetText()
        name.Items.Clear()
        str = "select * from [Student] where [class] = '" & Class_Name.Text & "' and [section] = '" & section.Text & "'"
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, cn)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "Student")
        ctr = ds.Tables("Student").Rows.Count - 1
        For i = 0 To ctr
            name.Items.Add(ds.Tables("Student").Rows(i)(5).ToString())
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error Accured" + Environment.NewLine + str + Environment.NewLine + "Please Contact to Developer", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `selectedRow`? Can you show code how you get values in there?

Comment: My guess would be that one of those early lines is making a change to a control that has an event handler that is making a change tot he grid and thus affecting the code you've shown us.  Do you have a `TextChanged` event handler for `Class_Name` or `section`?

Comment: @Fabio question edited

Comment: @jmcilhinney Nope

Comment: @John, but where you assign a row to the variable  `selectedRow`?

Comment: @Fabio Edited sir with whole function

Comment: Are there any other eventhandlers for **DataGridView2** or for any of those textboxes?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz No

Comment: did you try commenting `name.Text = selectedRow.Cells(12).Value` ? did the behaviour change? try to simplify the code as much as possible (for debugging reasons) - if none of it works, I'd try to create a very simple quick demo project...

Comment: Yes still same error

Comment: @John _"Yes still same error"_ if that reply was to PilgerstorferFranz's comment, please replace all the code in your question with that "simple demo project" (create it if you haven't already) and make sure it's a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If we can't reproduce your issue, we can only guess.

Comment: Apparently this is not an error. Something is happening that changes the data in DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex) and in your reference. Could you please provide the code parts in where DataGridView2 is used? Most likely that happens inside an event handler or perhaps you are using a background data loading mechanism that invalidates the grid at some point...

Comment: Do you use F10 (step over) or F11 (step into). F11 usually steps thorough all attached handlers (if not suppressed e.g. by attributes)?

Comment: Provided information not enough to answer this question (unless you like guessing).   @John, `selectedRow` reference cells of `DataGridView2` - that mean (based on the pictures) that values are updated after somehow after reading it. The code you provided not doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: Question updated.